# VS2010 with C++11 all feature support using QT creator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, qt-creator

I would like to ask a question about VS2010 IDE environment with all the C++11 features. Currently we need to build our software where some libraries need C++11 all feature support but we are now still running VS2010 environment and currently we are not upgrading our VS2010 to VS2017 at this moment.

So Is there any way to build these library with alternative mentods like installing QT creator on Windows platform so that can use g++ 4.9.3 or later same as on linux ubuntu? I found some website mentioning about Cygwin installed on Windows but seems not clear how to do.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QT installer provides binary versions built with MinGW as well as MinGW itself, so just use those.

[image: QT MinGW binaries]
[image: QT MinGW toolchain]

Comment: Hi, Rudolfs Bundulis. So if I install QT5.12.0 on Windows and build with VS2010, should enable all the C++11 features?

Comment: QT5.12.0 with MinGW 7.3.0 64 bit integrated should run?  Did you check this on your environment?

Comment: @DavidAlex Your question stated "So Is there any way to build these library with alternative mentods like installing QT creator on Windows platform so that can use g++ 4.9.3 or later same as on linux ubuntu?". Of course you won't be able to use MinGW in Visual Studio 2010 out of the box. What you can do is compile the C++11 parts with MinGW and everything else with Visual Studio or just use Qt Creator for everything.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try "compile the C++11 parts with MinGW and everything else with Visual Studio". Not sure whether is any compile dependency issue or not